# Symfony2 video streaming

Tags: symfony, streaming, video-streaming

I'm writing app in `symfony2` and I have a problem with video streaming.

If one action takes a long time to execute -  for example `1 minute`, the whole app is frozen (when opened in second tab) and must wait for end of that execution.

Where is the problem?

//EDIT

```
    public function streamAction($fileName) {

    $user = $this->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();
    $request = $this->getRequest();

    $uid = $request->get('uid') != 'null' ? $user->getId() : $request->get('uid');

    $libPath = $this->_libPath('Users', 'uid' . str_pad($uid, 6, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT));

    $file = pathinfo($fileName);
    $fileName = $file['basename'];
    $fileExt = $file['extension'];
    $filePath = realpath($libPath . $fileName);

    if (in_array($fileExt, $this->formats['video'])) {
        $mime = 'video';
    }

    if (in_array($fileExt, $this->formats['audio'])) {
        $mime = 'audio';
    }

    $mime .= '/' . $fileExt;

    header("Accept-Ranges: bytes");

    if (is_file($filePath)) {
        header("Content-type: $mime");
        if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'])) {

            $fp = fopen($filePath, 'rb');
            $size = filesize($filePath);
            $length = $size;
            $start = 0;
            $end = $size - 1;

            if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'])) {
                $c_start = $start;
                $c_end = $end;
                list(, $range) = explode('=', $_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'], 2);

                if (strpos($range, ',') !== false) {
                    header('HTTP/1.1 416 Requested Range Not Satisfiable');
                    header("Content-Range: bytes $start-$end/$size");
                    exit;
                }

                if ($range == '-') {
                    $c_start = $size - substr($range, 1);
                } else {
                    $range = explode('-', $range);
                    $c_start = $range[0];
                    $c_end = ( isset($range[1]) && is_numeric($range[1]) ) ? $range[1] : $size;
                }

                $c_end = ($c_end > $end) ? $end : $c_end;
                if ($c_start > $c_end || $c_start > $size - 1 || $c_end >= $size) {
                    header('HTTP/1.1 416 Requested Range Not Satisfiable');
                    header("Content-Range: bytes $start-$end/$size");
                    exit;
                }

                $start = $c_start;
                $end = $c_end;
                $length = $end - $start + 1;
                fseek($fp, $start);
                header('HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content');
                header('ETag: "' . md5(microtime()) . '"');
            }

            header("Content-Range: bytes $start-$end/$size");
            header("Content-Length: $length");
            header('Connection: Close');

            $buffer = 1024 * 8;
            while (!feof($fp) && ($p = ftell($fp)) <= $end) {
                if ($p + $buffer > $end) {
                    $buffer = $end - $p + 1;
                }
                set_time_limit(0);
                echo fread($fp, $buffer);
                flush();
            }
            fclose($fp);
        } else {
            header("Content-Length: " . filesize($filePath));
            readfile($filePath);
        }
    } else {
        echo "error";
    }
    die();
}
```

Problem is not code because symfony2 block not only with streaming but with other long time actions like downloading files.

Comment: Wheres your code? We can't guess what the problem is.

Comment: The problem sounds like more of an environment issue than a Symfony issue. have you tried running the streaming code outside of Symfony on the same server?

Comment: yes, with external script all is good buy i can`t authenticate user :/
If i use session file from symfony in my external script that script is blocking too

Comment: If that help you i saw that when i replace my security.yml to default security.yml that all is fine but i need to login from database

Answer (score 7):

If you use an OOP framework such as Symfony, why do still use procedural methods instead of what Symfony has to offer ?
For instance the [`StreamedResponse`](http://api.symfony.com/master/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/StreamedResponse.html) class.

I provided you a more OOP / Symfony oriented below,
However in case the provided Range is just `-`, you currently reset the range start to... The filesize? I am pretty sure this is not what you should do. I think you should double-check it!

Here is a reviewed version of streamAction() :

```
use SplFileInfo;
use RuntimeException;

// Symfony >= 2.1
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\StreamedResponse;

public function streamAction($fileName) {
    $user = $this->getUser();
    $request = $this->getRequest();

    // Create the StreamedResponse object
    $response = new StreamedResponse();

    $uid = $request->get('uid') != 'null' ? $user->getId() : $request->get('uid');
    $libPath = $this->_libPath('Users', 'uid' . str_pad($uid, 6, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT));

    try {
        $file = new SplFileObject($libPath . $fileName);
    }
    catch (RuntimeException $runtimeException) {
        // The file cannot be opened (permissions?)
        // throw new AnyCustomFileErrorException() maybe?
    }

    // Check file existence
    if (!($file->isFile())) {
        // The file does not exists, or is not a file.
        throw $this->createNotFoundException('This file does not exists, or is not a valid file.');
    }

    // Retrieve file informations
    $fileName = $file->getBasename();
    $fileExt  = $file->getExtension();
    $filePath = $file->getRealPath();
    $fileSize = $file->getSize();

    // Guess MIME Type from file extension
    if (in_array($fileExt, $this->formats['video'])) {
        $mime = 'video';
    } elseif (in_array($fileExt, $this->formats['audio'])) {
        $mime = 'audio';
    }

    $mime .= '/' . $fileExt;

    $response->headers->set('Accept-Ranges', 'bytes');
    $response->headers->set('Content-Type', $mime);

    // Prepare File Range to read [default to the whole file content]
    $rangeMin = 0;
    $rangeMax = $fileSize - 1;
    $rangeStart = $rangeMin;
    $rangeEnd = $rangeMax;

    $httpRange = $request->server->get('HTTP_RANGE');

    // If a Range is provided, check its validity
    if ($httpRange) {
        $isRangeSatisfiable = true;

        if (preg_match('/bytes=\h*(\d+)-(\d*)[\D.*]?/i', $httpRange, $matches)) {
            $rangeStart  = intval($matches[1]);

            if (!empty($matches[2])) {
                $rangeEnd  = intval($matches[2]);
            }
        } else {
            // Requested HTTP-Range seems invalid.
            $isRangeSatisfiable = false;
        }

        if ($rangeStart <= $rangeEnd) {
            $length = $rangeEnd - $rangeStart + 1;
        } else {
            // Requested HTTP-Range seems invalid.
            $isRangeSatisfiable = false;
        }

        if ($file->fseek($rangeStart) !== 0) {
            // Could not seek the file to the requested range: it might be out-of-bound, or the file is corrupted?
            // Assume the range is not satisfiable.
            $isRangeSatisfiable = false;

            // NB : You might also wish to throw an Exception here...
            // Depending the server behaviour you want to set-up.
            // throw new AnyCustomFileErrorException();
        }

        if ($isRangeSatisfiable) {
            // Now the file is ready to be read...
            // Set additional headers and status code.
            // Symfony < 2.4
            // $response->setStatusCode(206);
            // Or using Symfony >= 2.4 constants
            $response->setStatusCode(StreamedResponse::HTTP_PARTIAL_CONTENT);

            $response->headers->set('Content-Range', sprintf('bytes %d/%d', $rangeStart - $rangeEnd, $fileSize));
            $response->headers->set('Content-Length', $length);
            $response->headers->set('Connection', 'Close');
        } else {
            $response = new Response();

            // Symfony < 2.4
            // $response->setStatusCode(416);
            // Or using Symfony >= 2.4 constants
            $response->setStatusCode(StreamedResponse::HTTP_REQUESTED_RANGE_NOT_SATISFIABLE);
            $response->headers->set('Content-Range', sprintf('bytes */%d', $fileSize));

            return $response;
        }
    } else {
        // No range has been provided: the whole file content can be sent
        $response->headers->set('Content-Length', $fileSize);
    }

    // At this step, the request headers are ready to be sent.
    $response->prepare($request);
    $response->sendHeaders();

    // Prepare the StreamCallback
    $response->setCallback(function () use ($file, $rangeEnd) {
        $buffer = 1024 * 8;

        while (!($file->eof()) && (($offset = $file->ftell()) < $rangeEnd)) {
            set_time_limit(0);

            if ($offset + $buffer > $rangeEnd) {
                $buffer = $rangeEnd + 1 - $offset;
            }

            echo $file->fread($buffer);
        }

        // Close the file handler
        $file = null;
    });

    // Then everything should be ready, we can send the Response content.
    $response->sendContent();

    // DO NOT RETURN $response !
    // It has already been sent, both headers and body.
}
```

Comment: Good solution, but $isSatisfiableRange is only set to false. So if (!$isSatisfiableRange) will always pass! I think you've missed setting $isSatisfiableRange to true at the beginning of code (just after if ($httpRange)). Your code needs some improvements and then it works well.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that, indeed I missed this small point. My answer was focus on the Symfony behaviour, not the algorithm itself, though.